# Why we use #!/bin/bash in Bash script?

Tags: bash, shell

What is the significant of using **#!/bin/bash**  in the starting of bash script? Can we write a bash script without **#!/bin/bash** ?

Comment: Google for shebang: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This line is called shebang. It’s a ‚magic‘ line telling the program loader (kernel) how to execute a script on unixoid systems.

Cf. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)